# How to Model a multi-participant conversation system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, message, rails-activerecord

I am new to Rails (and programming) and after going through a few tutorials, I am designing a messaging app to test my skills.

The situation I am modelling is where a user can message 2+ other users. Here's what I came up with

- A conversation has many participants (users) and many messages
  (message).
- A user has many conversation and many messages.
- A message belongs to users (sender + recipients) and belongs to a conversation.

The ActiveRecord model is then:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, :through :conversation
  has_many :conversations # or is belongs_to :conversation 
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  belongs_to :user # or is it has_many :users
end
```

Or do I have to add a 4th interface inbox

```
class Inbox < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :conversations
end
```

and I would change the user and conversation models to be

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :inbox
  has_many :conversations, :through :inbox
  has_many :messages, :through :conversation
end

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inbox
  has_many :messages
  belongs_to :users
end
```

The second option looks redundant.
So yeah, I am fuzzy about the relationship/association between a conversation and users. All input to enlighten me is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first way is better in my opinion, but it should look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  has_many :user_conversations
  has_many :conversations, through: :user_conversations
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  has_many :user_conversations
  has_many :users, through: :user_conversations
end

# join table between users and conversations
class UserConversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

The reason is that a user can have many conversations, and a conversation can have many users. You need to create the join table UserConversation to accommodate this.

Also, the easiest way to find out which model should belong to the other model is to ask which model should have the foreign key of the other model. The one with the foreign keys `belongs_to` the other model.

Comment: I see what you did; you abstracted only part of the relationship between a user and a conversation.
Thanks! I'm testing it rn.

Thanks for the tip too.

Comment: Yes and no, I am still on the rails console trying to get traversing the relationships right. (sender/receipient/sent_messages/received_messages etc.)

yeah upvoted.